# The WS-Management service cannot process the request .The service is configured to not accept any remote shell requests

Tags: iis

We have Windows Server 2019 and I am trying to enable IIS feature on it but getting this error 'The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The service is configured to not accept any remote shell requests.'.
i have enabled remote shell access, but still i'm getting same error

Any help would be appreciate. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when AllowRemoteShellAccess is disabled for a group policy, you can try below steps to slove the issue:

1. Open Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
2. Open Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components >Windows Remote Shell.
3. Double-click `AllowRemoteShellAccess`.
4. Set its value to `Enabled`.
5. Click OK.
6. Open a CMD window.
7. Run the following command: `gpupdate/force`.

Comment: This worked for me but required a server reboot.